# Functions: Detirmining values a & b

Tags: functions

**The problem**

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined over the real number set $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$$
\begin{split}
g(x) &= 1-x+x^2\\
f(x) &= ax+b
\end{split} 
$$

If $g(f(x)) = 9x^2 - 9x + 3$, determine all the possible values of $a$ and $b$.

Basically i'm completely thrown by this. How would you begin to work out the values of $a$ & $b$? What sort of tests?

I get functions, but have just never been asked something like this, any help simplifying this would be much appreciated.

I'm not looking for all the possible values of $a$ & $b$. Just someone to tell me what direction to go to find that out.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$g(x)= 1-x+x^2$ and $    f(x)=ax+b$

$\implies g(f(x))=g(ax+b)$
$=1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2=a^2x^2+x(2ab-a)+1-b+b^2$

Again,  $g(f(x)) = 9x^2 - 9x + 3$

Equate the coefficients of the different powers of $x$